# Let $P(x)$ a polynomial and $P',P'',P'''...$ its derivatives. Proof that:

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $P(x)$ a polynomial and $P',P'',Pi'''...$ its derivatives. Proof that:

$$\int P(x)e^{ax}dx = \frac{e^{ax}}{a}(1-\frac{P'}{a}+\frac{P''}{a^{2}}-\frac{P'''}{a^{3}}+...)$$

Comment: You should post your attempt otherwise your question will be closed Miguel.

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int P(x)e^{ax}dx$$
Integrate by part:
$$I=\dfrac Pa e^{ax }-\dfrac 1 a \int P'e^{ax}dx$$
integrate by part again :
$$I=\dfrac Pa e^{ax }-\dfrac {P'} {a^2}e^{ax } +\dfrac 1 {a^2} \int P''e^{ax}dx$$
$$I=\dfrac Pa e^{ax }-\dfrac {P'} {a^2}e^{ax }+\dfrac {P''} {a^3}e^{ax }  +...+....(-1)^n\dfrac 1 {a^n} \int P^{(n)}e^{ax}dx$$
The first term must have  $P$ at the numerator. Maybe a typo ?

You can surely take it from there.